# Limit crossover problem

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

If $f$ is a real function satisfying $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=-\infty$ then there must exist $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $0<r<\epsilon$ such that $f(a-\epsilon)\le 0\le f(a+\epsilon)$.

Comment: what does $r$ have to do with the question?

Comment: So what's the question? What have you tried?

Comment: If it is $\exists a,\exists r>0$ such that for all $\epsilon>r$, $f(a-\epsilon)\leq0\leq f(a+\epsilon)$. Then take $a=(\sup\{x:\ \forall t\in(-\infty,x)\ f(t)<0\}+\inf\{x:\ \forall t\in(x,+\infty)\ f(t)>0\})/2$ and $r=a-\sup\{x:\ \forall t\in(-\infty,x)\ f(t)<0\}$.